# How to register ContentObserver for media volume change?

Tags: java, android, service, contentobserver

I encountered a problem when I wanted to implement volume change detection.
As the change detection has to be detected in the background via Service, I can not intercept volume key presses.

I've tried ContentObserver to listen for volume settings change, but it didn't worked.
But I've dig a bit more, and found that my ContentObserver detects volume change when I register it like this:

```
this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver( 
    android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, 
    mSettingsContentObserver );
```

I've tried to change the first parameter - the URI of setting to listen, if I understand correctly. But I achieved nothing. So, how can this be done? I don't want to update my UI(I'm setting Seekbar to certain positin) on every settings change.

So, how do I register content observer to listen for media volume change?

Here's the code of ContentObserver:

```
public class SettingsContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

 public SettingsContentObserver(Handler handler) {
     super(handler);
 } 

 @Override
 public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
      return super.deliverSelfNotifications(); 
 }

 @Override
 public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
     super.onChange(selfChange);
     myMethod();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your onChange meathod to the following

```
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    super.onChange(selfChange);

    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    int delta=previousVolume-currentVolume;

    if(delta>0)
    {
        Logger.d("Decreased");
        previousVolume=currentVolume;
    }
    else if(delta<0)
    {
        Logger.d("Increased");
        previousVolume=currentVolume;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but this is not exactly that I want. Sure, it will prevent updating my UI, but still it's called when any setting changed. The question is how to register ContentObserver for some specific settings.

Comment: That cannot be done as there is no obserevr available for it. What you are currently doing is, observing all the descendants in the hierarchy of System. Settings. Read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver(android.net.Uri, boolean, android.database.ContentObserver)

Comment: How can I use content observer to detect holding down volume button?

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor for changes to a specific stream by using a more specific URI than Settings.System.CONTENT_URI.  The method `Settings.System.getUriFor()` will return the URI for a specific stream.

For example:

```
Uri uri = Settings.System.getUriFor(Settings.System.VOLUME_SETTINGS[AudioManager.STREAM_RING]);
appContext.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri, true, myObserver);
```

Comment: How can I use content observer to detect holding down volume button?

Comment: I also have a question with content observer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256364/volume-always-the-same

Comment: `Settings.System.VOLUME_SETTINGS` is not available

Answer (score 0):

Andy Dennie:

I have just tested approach suggested by you:

`Uri uri = Settings.System
.getUriFor(Settings.System.VOLUME_SETTINGS[AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC]);
appContext.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri, true, myObserver);`

and if I register for this URI, volume changes on STREAM_MUSIC aren't detected. But If I use

`android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI`

it works perfectly.