# how to set BroadCastReceiver for volume keys to open new activity

Tags: android

If an user presses volume key up and down, is it possible to detect it in my broadcast receiver?

I need the full code.
This question have been already asked on http://stackoverflow.com but was not answered properly.

I have been searching for a solution to this question from the past three weeks but unable to find proper answer.

I want code snipet for:

```
1)     public class MainActivity extends Activity {}
2)     public class VolumeKeyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {}
3)     AndroidManifest.xml
```

please help!!

Answer (score 0):

There is not a supported broadcast event for volume button press (change). There are 2 ways to listen for volume button presses.

1) ContentObserver. See [How to register ContentObserver for media volume change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192253/how-to-register-contentobserver-for-media-volume-change)

2) onKeyEvent. See [Android - Volume Buttons used in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874743/android-volume-buttons-used-in-my-application/2875006#2875006)

If you want a BroadcastReceiver, one of the two above can fire a broadcast event - sendBroadcast see  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)