# Volume always the same?

Tags: java, android, string, algorithm, function

I have the following code, and I want to  get the difference of the previous volume before holding the volume button and the current volume. But, when I was debugging, I found that the previous and current volume is always the same:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
package curlybrace.ruchir.ivebeenstuckfortwodays;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Handler;


/**
 * Created by ruchir on 2/5/2016.
 */
public class volumeCheck extends ContentObserver {
    int previousVolume;
    Context context;

    public volumeCheck(Context c, Handler handler) {
        super(handler); //Creates a new handler
        context=c; //variable context, defined earlier, is set equal to c, context of service.

        AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); //retrieve an AudioManager for handling management of volume, ringer modes and audio routing.
        previousVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); //The volume that we get before the `onChange` is called
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        processVolumeChange(previousVolume, currentVolume);
    }

    public void processVolumeChange(int previousVolume, int currentVolume) {

        MyService mService = new MyService();
        mService.volumeCheck(previousVolume - currentVolume); //Method in my service


    }
}
```

I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days now, but I don't know why the values are the same. Please help.

### Edit:

I have the following code in my service's `onCreate`:

```
     mSettingsContentObserver = new volumeCheck(this, new Handler());
   getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, mSettingsContentObserver);
```

Thanks

Comment: What Uri Are you registering this `ContentObserver` with?

Comment: I have the following code in my service's `onCreate`: 
        `mSettingsContentObserver = new volumeCheck(this, new Handler());
      getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, mSettingsContentObserver);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably aren't changing the media volume on your device. To verify go to Settings->Sound & Notification and try changing the Media volume found there.

[image]

You probably also want to update update your `previousVolume` after a change too:

```
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    super.onChange(selfChange);

    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    processVolumeChange(currentVolume);
}

public void processVolumeChange(int currentVolume) {
    MyService mService = new MyService();
    mService.volumeCheck(previousVolume - currentVolume); //Method in my service
    previousVolume = currentVolume;
}
```

Comment: I am still not getting my toast from my service though. I think I wasn't debugging correctly. I put a breakpoint on this line: `processVolumeChange(previousVolume, currentVolume);`.

Comment: And now I am getting a null pointer exception in my service when I try to access it...

Comment: Ok but are you getting the correct values now when you are debugging?

Comment: No, I'm still not. I am extremely confused now. I am getting a null pointer exception, and I dont think I am debugging correctly

Comment: [Would you like to continue this discussion in chat?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102844/volume-issue)

Comment: Right. I thought at first you just wanted to update a single static int field. If you need to other things it will not work.

Comment: So how can i fix that?

Comment: And why can't I just do this?

Comment: `MyService mService = new MyService();
        mService.volumeCheck(previousVolume - currentVolume); //Method in my service`

Comment: You can't do that because to start a service you're supposed to use the startService method on a context. Best to ask another question to have that explained or look up an existing answer.